# Is it possible to extend a Modelica connector without redefining "potential" and flow connect equations?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have created a simple connector to handle 2D coordinate pairs. The connector includes Real potential variables x and y.

```
connector Coordinate_2D "2D Coordinate Connector"
  Real x;
  Real y;  
end Coordinate_2D;
```

I want to extend the connector and create a 3D version like is shown below:

```
connector Coordinate_3D "Coordinate connector: x,y,z"
  extends Coordinate_2D;
  Real z;
end Coordinate_3D;
```

I am able to do this, but it doesn't seem like the connector is really extended. It recognizes that Coordinate_3D contains x, y, and z variables, but it doesn't seem to properly maintain the connector equations for the x and y potential variables.

I created a simple converter class to convert a 2D connector into a 3D connector. I expected that I should be able to simply define the equation for the new variable z and the x and y values would be automatically inferred because the 3D connector is extended from the 2D connector. So I expecteded that I could simply use:

```
model CoordinateConverter_2D_to_3D "x,y to x,y,z converter"
  Real defaultZValue = 0;

equation 
  coordinate_3D.z = defaultZValue;
end CoordinateConverter_2D_to_3D;
```

But this does not seem to work. The translator states that variables coordinate_2D.x, coordinate_2D.y, coordinate_3D.x, and coordinate_3D.y are unused so they are removed from the simulation, leaving only 2 equations and 2 unknowns. If rather than translating I use the "Check" option in Dymola, it shows 6 equations and 6 unknowns.

In order to get the behavior I expect, I must manually define the equations for the x and y variables as well:

```
model CoordinateConverter_2D_to_3D "x,y to x,y,z converter"
  Real defaultZValue = 0;

equation 
  coordinate_3D.x = coordinate_2D.x;
  coordinate_3D.y = coordinate_2D.y;
  coordinate_3D.z = defaultZValue;
end CoordinateConverter_2D_to_3D;
```

Is there something that I am missing that would allow the 3D connector equations to be extended from the 2D connector as I expect?

I understand that in this case it is trivial to add the two additional equations, but in my real case I have a more complex connector that includes multiple stream variables, a flow variable, and multiple potential variables. So it would be better to be able to simply extend additional variables to the connector rather than redefining the connector from scratch.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: How do you connect them? The connect equations are only generated if you connect two connectors together.

Comment: Adrian, I assumed that the portion of the 3d connector that is inherited from the 2d connector would connect in the same way as two 2d connectors. And then only the additional connect equation to handle the new variables that are added to the base connector would need to be defined. As it stands now I had to redefine all of the connect equations in the CoordinateConverter_2D_to_3D model. Thanks, Justin

Comment: If you use extends and you use the new extended class in the place of the old class it will connect all 3 elements. If you want in some places to use the old one and in some other places use the new one then you need to use replaceable. replaceable connector Coordinate = Coordinate_2D;  Coordinate c1, c2;